# How to use React with function component and hooks ONLY?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, components, react-hooks

Having a React project with some component written in Class style and some others written in Hooks styles make the newcomers confuse and harder to reuse common logic. Is there a way, for example:

- An alternative library like Preact, Inferno,... which compatible with React but only support hooks
- Or an ESLint feature that warning every time someone try to create a React class component
- ...

to prevent my developer from writing Class component, as I want all components in my React project to be functional component with hooks only.

Comment: I think this rule might do it for you: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prefer-stateless-function.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also wanted a lint rule that accomplished this so I wrote [eslint-plugin-react-prefer-function-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-prefer-function-component).

The only components that can not be written as a function component are those that implement `componentDidCatch`, so by default components implementing that method are allowed. This option is configurable.

[eslint-plugin-react/prefer-stateless-function](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prefer-stateless-function.md) (mentioned in other answers) allows class components that have state or implement any class methods.

Comment: Yeah this what I'm looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

use eslint's react plugin  https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react and set `react/prefer-stateless-function` to true in your eslint config

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the `prefer-stateless-function` lint only warning with stateless component. I want the warning also display with stateful component as well. Because I want 100% of my components are written in functions with hooks

Comment: Maybe this will help https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-no-class